# What would be a publish error on Wolfram Cloud for a well-functioning Manipulate?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I wrote the game 'Deal or No Deal' as below, which works well in Mathematica (v13.3).

```
Manipulate[Column[ { Grid[ {{ 
  Row[{ "Prize Money : ", 
    If[show == True,  Row[{"$ ", Last@rs}], " ??? "] }],  
  Row[{ "Select Card : ",  
    Control[{{select, 1, ""}, Complement[Range[25], append], 
      ControlType -> PopupMenu, ImageSize -> 40, 
      Enabled -> If[go, True, False]}]  }], 
  Row[{ "Expected Value : ", "$ ", 
    Floor@N@Mean[Complement[rs, Map[rs[[#]] &, append]]]   }]  }},
 Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {{18.5, 16, 20}, 3}, 
Spacings -> {1, 1} ],  
Row[{ Button[ "New Game", { append = {},  rs = RandomSample[values], 
   show = False, go = True , 
   append2 = {{0.01, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 
      500, 750, 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 
      200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 750000, 1000000}}   }, 
  ImageSize -> 80], Spacer[10], 
 Button["Yes, Show Prize Money", { show = True, go = False }, 
  ImageSize -> 150], Spacer[10], 
 Button["No, Next Open Card", { show = False, go = True, 
   append = Union@Append[append, select], 
   append2 = 
    Append[append2, Complement[rs, Map[rs[[#]] &, append]]]  }, 
  ImageSize -> 150, Enabled -> If[show, False, True]  ], 
 Spacer[10],  "Do you agree to a $", 
 ToString[
  Floor[ Max[ N@0.1 Mean[Complement[rs, Map[rs[[#]] &, append]]], 
    1000]    ] ], " deal in prize money?"     }, 
ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 15}} ],    
Grid[Partition[
 Table[Item[
   Pane[  If[ MemberQ[append, num[[i]]], rs[[i]], num[[i]]] , 
    ImageSize -> {55, 30}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}], 
   Background -> LightGray], {i, 1, Length[num]}] , 13], 
Spacings -> {.1, .1}, Dividers -> All, FrameStyle -> White], "",    
Dynamic@BoxWhiskerChart[PadRight[Union@append2, 25, {{}}], 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log", Background -> White, ImageSize -> 735,
  Joined -> True, ChartLabels -> Placed[Range[25], Axis], 
 ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 
     1000000}, Automatic}, {None, None}},
 GridLines -> {{5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, {Log[10^-2], Log[10^-1], 
    Log[1], Log[10], Log[10^2], Log[10^3], Log[10^4], Log[10^5], 
    Log[10^6]}}]  , "",    
Grid[Partition[
 Table[Item[
   Pane[  Style[values[[i]], 11,  
     If[ MemberQ[Map[ rs[[#]] &, append], values[[i]]], 
      Lighter@Gray, Black] ]   , ImageSize -> {55, 30}, 
    Alignment -> {Center, Center}], Background -> LightGray], {i, 
   1, Length[num]}] , 13], Spacings -> {.1, .1}, Dividers -> All, 
FrameStyle -> White]  }], AppearanceElements -> {},  
SynchronousInitialization -> False,  
Initialization :> (show = False; go = True; append = {};  
rs = RandomSample[{0.01, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 
  500, 750, 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 
  200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 750000, 1000000}];    
values = {0.01, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 750,
  1000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 
 400000, 500000, 750000, 1000000};    num = Insert[Range[25], "?", -1];    
append2 = {{0.01, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 
  750, 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 200000, 
  300000, 400000, 500000, 750000, 1000000}};) ]
```

However, this code does not work well on Wolfram Cloud.
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/402054c3-a236-401b-8440-b519d93dcd5a

What would be a Publish error on Wolfram Cloud for a well-functioning Manipulate?

[image]

Comment: Maybe localizing variables will stabilize it: `DynamicModule[{show, go, append, rs, values, num, append2, select}, ...]` but I wouldn't expect a nice UX from this Manipulate anyway, Cloud's Dynamic GUIs are known to be very slow for anything but simplest cases.

Comment: It has nothing to do with setting local variables. Is it the performance limit of Wolfram Cloud?

Comment: I mean, once I added `DynamicModule` mentioned above I no longer witnessed an unevaluate `BarWhiskerChart` in the output but the UI was unusable anyway. And the latter part has nothing to do with local variables. I would not say it is a performance limit but UIs written for Cloud need to be more written very carefully. That is a long topic though and I am afraid that the conclusion might be: just don't. But I may be not up to date as I stopped writing Dynamic UIs for Cloud a long time ago.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm thinking of redesigning it step by step from the beginning.